# Как установить proxy в Genymotion на всю систему?

Tags: android, proxy, virtualbox, genymotion, android-emulator

Мой прокси привязан к моему Ip.
Я устанавливаю его в Настройках Genymotion и настройках Wifi ставил. 
Суть в том, что в браузере - работает отлично.
А когда к примеру устанавливаю Telegram, то в нем видно мой реальный Ip. 
Как установить на всю систему proxy, чтобы в любом приложение прокси работало?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел решение, поставил ProxyDroid - и все отлично работает